# Python- Turning user input into a list

Tags: python, input

Is there a way to ask for user input and turn their input into a list, tuple, or string for that matter? I want a series of numbers to insert into a matrix. I could tell them to type all the numbers into the console with no spaces and iterate through them but are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply do as follows:

```
user_input = input("Please provide list of numbers separated by comma, e.g. 1,2,3: ")

a_list =  list(map(float,user_input.split(',')))
print(a_list)
# example result: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: nice thanks. Literally just learned about maps today so I didn't think to use it

Comment: should really use a try/except when casting,  there are many ways this will raise an error

Comment: I would also recommend separating elements by spaces and using plain `.split()` because it handles multiple spaces between items automatically. i.e. `'1 2  3   4      5'.split()` --> `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

Comment: You both right. My answer is one of many possibilities. Please feel free to make alternative answers.

Answer (score 2):

NumPy supports MATLAB-style matrix definitions if you're using it:

```
import numpy as np
s = raw_input('Enter the matrix:')
matrix = np.matrix(s)
```

e.g.

```
Enter the matrix:1 2 3; 4 5 3
```

sets the `matrix` to:

```
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 3]])
```

Separate entries on each row by spaces and rows by semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a list that automatically places a comma whenever it finds a space between numbers use this:

```
query=input("enter a bunch of numbers: ")
a_list = list(map(int,query.split())) 
print(a_list)
```

*split() will split them with commas, without input

*eg. 1 2 3 4 5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]